# Android ScrollView stops working when a grandchild is removed dynamically

Tags: android, scrollview

I will try to be as specific as possible as I can not post the actual code .It is a work related code and I am not allowed to. 
I have a use case very similar to gmail app. I need to display a list of objects , let's say a list of emails received. The list is dynamic and it can grow as well as shrink. The vertical ScrollView works well as the list grows. The problem happens, when a user deletes one of the objects just like they archive an email from emails list. At this point the scrollview stops working even if the list is longer than the screen height. I can not scroll to seethe entire list. If new object gets added , say user receives an email, the scrollview starts to work again. I am not able to understand what goes wrong when the list shrinks? Both adding an object dynamically to a list as well as removing an object modify the list in some way. The scrollView works with former case while it doesn't work with the latter. My XML is as below. I am not doing anything fancy, not at all overriding any scrollview events. And, just have some code on touch event for deleting the objects from the list. What am I doing wrong or missing completely? Your suggestions will be very helpful for me!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/snugfit"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/snugfit"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/snugfit"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/snugfit"
tools:context="xactivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <!-- This will hold a dynamic list -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/outerll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >;

        <!--Sample dynamically added elements -->
          <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/in1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >;
            <!--Text View -->
            <!--Image View -->
            <!--Has on touch event implemented -->
        </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/in2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >;
            <!--Text View -->
            <!--Image View -->
            <!--Has on touch event implemented -->
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: How do you remove your item in your list? And when you remove your item, do you call "onDataSetChanged()" on your Adapter?

Comment: ListView or a ScrollView? the latter being an overkill! If later is the case, i'd suggest you go through some basic Android tuts first!

Comment: I need to see both methods that remove and add child element. Maybe the problem lies in choosing the parent ViewGroup.

Comment: @Skynet, sure. I am just a beginner and I have a lot to read and absorb. I am not using ListView at all. I have a liner layout as ScrollView's direct child and I build Linear layouts for every item that needs to appear. So it's ScrollView->LinearLayout->List of LinearLayouts. Is it wrong?

Comment: @user2686211 There is no wrong or right but it makes you look like you derive pleasure from pain. There are many problems associated with list like what you're facing now (adding / removing child) and memory management to name the few (all views you attach will stick forever). You can use this scenario only when you build custom View with only a few fixed number of children.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the list will not get refreshed once after you deleted or including the data into the list. try to refer [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) method for to refresh the listView.